# h:outputLink not generating full context path for self linking page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

We have a legacy JSF application running on jetty. It has pages like `/foo/bar/mypage.xhtml` with outputLink tags like: `<h:outputLink value="?param1=value1">Click</h:outputLink>`. These links are being generated without any context, and so when clicked, the browser correctly links to the current page with the specified parameters.

We recently installed Xebia's [XForwardedFilter](https://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/XForwardedFilter) to fix issues with running the app behind a proxy. With it enabled, though, the link is getting generated by jsf with the context (which from my understanding is the correct behavior). Unfortunately, the context doesn't include anything after the last `/`, so the current page is not included in the link. For the example above, the link becomes `/foo/bar/?param1=value1` instead of the desired `/foo/bar/mypage.jsf?param1=value1`

The workaround is to include the current page for the link value: `<h:outputLink value="mypage.jsf?param1=value1">Click</h:outputLink>`. The problem is that there are a lot of these links in the application and some of them are in includes which will require passing an additional parameter to indicate the page that should be referenced.

Is there a way to get the outputLink to generate the full context? Alternatively, if we could disable the context generation altogether so that the prior behavior occurs, that would work as well.